# What is the HTML equivalent of #define in C/C++?

Tags: html, cordova, include

I have multiple HTML files which vary only by a little - a few bits of text and Javascript constants here and there.  I want to make it easy to maintain one master version and make generating the variants simple.

Something like the compile time substitution in C/C++ would be simple and perfect:

```
#define CONSTANT 1.23456
```

**How?  Any ideas?**

---

Additional info:

- Using HTML 5
- These HTML files are for use in PhoneGap, so no    server-side stuff allowed.

Comment: That "simple and perfect" line is actually not perfect at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a templating engine for that. I for one am very content with this one from twitter http://twitter.github.com/hogan.js/

Answer (score 3):

There is no such mechanism in HTML in practice. Things like this are handled using various tools, such as advanced editors, preprocessing tools, and server-side technologies like PHP. You could even [use a C preprocessor](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/cpre.html) if you like, though most people use something different.

On the theory side, HTML has the “entity” mechanism as per SGML and XML. It was never implemented in HTML browsers, even though entities are part of SGML and HTML was nominally SGML-based. (The so-called “character entities” like `&eacute;` for é have been implemented on an ad hoc basis, not via an implementation of the entity mechanism.)

Browsers that support true XHTML (and not just XHTML processed by HTML rules) implement the entity mechanism, so you can actually write e.g.

```
<!ENTITY CONSTANT "1.23456">
```

in a DTD and

```
&CONSTANT;
```

in document content. See [demo](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/test/entitydef.xhtml). But this works only when the document is served with an XHTML media type, which in turn prevents old versions of IE from displaying the page at all.

Comment: thanks for your answer - interesting lesson, but not sure if it helps my code! cheers